# version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: docker, pytorch, ubuntu-16.04, glibc, libc

I'm trying to install PyTorch on ARMv7(32-bit) architecture but PyTorch doesn’t have official ARMv7 builds so i tried [this unofficial build](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-1-3-wheels-for-raspberry-pi-python-3-7/58580).

It installed successfully but when I import torch I get the following error

```
>>import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
```

I tried the following

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

but it seams like that i have the newest version of libc6

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu11).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  busybox-initramfs cpio initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core klibc-utils libdbusmenu-gtk4 libklibc
  libllvm3.8 libmircommon5 linux-base
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

Here is my GLIBCXX and GLIBC versions that i have:

```
strings /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.17
```

Ldd version:

```
ldd --version

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11) 2.23
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

My OS:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

So is it possible to install GLIBC_2.28 on my machine?

Comment: Double-post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249347/version-glibc-2-28-not-found

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> So is it possible to install GLIBC_2.28 on my machine?

It is possible, but the chances of you making a mistake and rendering your system un-bootable are quite high. It is also very likely that doing so will break something *else* on your system (this is the reason distributions do not usually update the version of GLIBC from the one they originally shipped with).

A much better solution is to built PyTorch targeting your system (i.e. using your "normal" toolchain).

P.S. GLIBCXX has *nothing* to do with your problem, and just adds noise to your question.

Comment: I f*** up my system installing  GLIBC_2.28. Good answer

Comment: I was about to make the same mistake .... lucky me!

Comment: will avoid ruining my day, you guys deserve the heaven

Answer (score 5):

for anyone in AWS using serverless framework
I have the issue with python Eve (flask, bcrypt) (python 3.8)
add this packages with versions to requirements.txt

cryptography==3.4.8
bcrypt==3.2.2

Comment: This worked for me, moving one conda env to another (Windows to Linux). Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same problem trying to run Node.js 18 on Ubuntu 18 LTS. I read a lot about the nasty risks of trying to upgrade GLIBC, so in the end I opted for the safe (albeit overkill) option of upgrading to Ubuntu 20 LTS. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was as follows:

1. I was using a docker, with a path mapping to my host home directory (`~` in docker is mapped to `~` on host).
2. I had a venv in `~/venv` (in both host and docker).
3. I installed some libraries on this venv on host
4. When running from docker, I got the error.

This happened because when installing libraries, some code gets compiled on the specific architecture/os, which was different in the docker.

The solution I used was to remove the venv, and install everything from within the docker. [This required to allow the docker access to the web and to internal company servers]

---

On why to do it like this in the first place - in another episode.

Answer (score -1):

## WAIT

It was fairly easy for me to fix it.

I have installed wrong version of the websocat on my machine.

So from here https://github.com/vi/websocat/releases
I installed https://github.com/vi/websocat/releases/download/v1.8.0/websocat_1.8.0_newer_i386.deb
which caused above issues

and then i installed the another debian
https://github.com/vi/websocat/releases/download/v1.8.0/websocat_1.8.0_older_i386.deb

That solve it.

So choose the correct version and have fun.

Happy debugging :)